# Handle external keyboard and software keyboard

Tags: ios, bluetooth, keyboard

My app uses a BarCode Scanner (Inateck BCST-10), connected with bluetooth, with a HID profile (external hardware keyboard). By default an UITextField is firstResponder to catch barcode from the scanner.

When the scanner is offline, the software keyboard appears. I would like to handle that case.

What I did when UIKeyboardWillShowNotification:

```
mytextfield.resignFirstResponder()
```

But how to get back the firstResponder on my UITextfield when the scanner go online ?

Comment: are you working with ObjectiveC or Shift ? we can handle that offline and online status change with help of reachbulity class. Keyboard show and hide case also hanle with textfield deligate methods. No need notifications. Please paste your code here . If you dont need keyboard , just return NO in - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;  method and show your custom keybord based on conditions

Comment: Swift. I know how to handle keyboard, I just need to know when the external keyboard is disconnected/connectez to hide the keyboard when it's offline.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you find a solution?